# Is there a way to extract the timestamp format in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panda Series which is a timestamp field and was imported in String format. How can I get the timestamp format of this field?

One way is to validate with each timestamp format

`pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce', format="%m-%d-%y").notnull()`

`pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce', format="%d-%m-%y").notnull()`

---

But this approach is not scalable as there are lot of timestamp formats and it will also be expensive operation validating every timestamps.

Is there a better way to extract the timestamp format ?

Comment: Are you trying to extract multiple formats from the same series?

Comment: No, there will only be one format in the series, I want to extract the format from it

Comment: You can not "get" the format this way, you should give the format to pandas. But that's your question, I get it now